# How to make your iPhone beep every 5 minutes

Tags: iphone

How to make your iPhone beep every 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [interval timer app](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=interval%20timer%20app), and customize the sound/beep of it.
For example https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/everyhour-alarm/id963108472?l=en&mt=8